# Installed dependency in node_modules is missing node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have 2 TS packages. `project-1` is installed as a dependency in `project-2`. I am able to import and access all type definitions of `project-1`. But the dependencies (node_modules directory) in `project-1` are not found. This is because the `node_modules` directory of `project-1` is not present.
Do I really need to manually `npm install` inside that `node_modules/project-1` directory? Or should the node_modules directory be published to npm as well?  If so, should I remove it from `tsconfig.json's` `exclude` property? I think `node_modules` should be in `.gitignore` right?

Just to be clear:

```
./project-2/node_modules                         // this exists
./project-2/node_modules/project-1               // this exists
./project-2/node_modules/project-1/node_modules  // this does not

/* only after manually running npm install in 
 * ./project-2/node_modules/project-1 the node_modules folder appears.
 */
```

****project-1****
** package.json**

```
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "commonjs",
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

**.gitignore**

```
node_modules
dist
logs
tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
.env
```

**.npmignore**
this file is empty.

How do I ensure that the node_modules directory is present when installing an npm package?

Answer (score 0):

The node_modules directory should not be published to npm registry. It should only contain dependencies installed during the development of your project. To ensure that the node_modules directory is present when installing an npm package, you need to run npm install or yarn install in your project root directory after you have installed your dependencies. The node_modules directory should also be listed in your .gitignore file to avoid committing it to your Git repository.

Comment: For some reason, `./project-2/node_modules/project-1` is not automatically being created when I run `npm install project-1`. `./project-2/node_modules` is present however...